# How to estimates monthly/daily sales of an item using Amazon Advertising API

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have looked into the responses of "ItemSeach ()" and "lookUp()" functions in Amazon Advertising API and
could not find a possible way to get daily/monthly sales of an item.

Popular product research software like , JungleScout, ProfitPhonix, AMZ tracker etc do display Number of monthly sales but all of them show different results.

Does Amazon provide this information ? If not then how the above software are estimating it?

I think when they fetch the ASIN information, they do store "some thing" in their DB and next time when the same ASIN is pulled again then the estimated sales are roughly calculated based on DB previous value/score.

Any help will be highly appreciated .

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is not a solution, but here is a reply from UnicornSmasher I found, it may help to save time searching for something that doesn't exist.

> constantine We just took all of the bulk data from the products that are being tracked in AMZ Tracker and applied a formula to it all. If you have specific products that are way off please let us know! Certain categories we had less data on. This is version 1 of the research tool, so I'm sure it will continue to improve quickly over time.

Here is the link to question and answer:
[amz forum](http://community.amztracker.com/discussion/814/unicorn-smasher-a-new-amazon-product-research-tool)

So, now, the question is 'What formula do they use?'
Let me know if you come up with an idea :)

Answer (score 0):

Let me tell you first that if you're not the part of the Amazon data team you can't get the sales numbers of any product. And, its probably not easy to estimate sales using Amazon advertising API. You need to constantly track a huge number of products to estimate the sales. Here I can explain how [AMZ Insight](http://www.amzinsight.com) an Amazon tracking tool estimates the sales of any product.

They constantly track a few thousand products from all the categories and collect massive data. Then their in-house data scientist analyze the data to form the sales estimating algorithm. Relationship of multiple data points plots a scattered graph which means of course sales estimates are not 100 percent right.

Data is continuously gathered and analyzed by tracking the Best Seller Rank (BSR), Buybox, reviews and more factors. Then the relationship between this data is formed to come up with the unit sales. Once this relationship is in place then it is much easier to estimate monthly sales and revenue for the product.